# <* text-align:justify *> functionality For divs (boxs)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have many boxes with different sizes; the sizes are unknown. I would like to use a CSS specification that does the same as `text-align:justify` does words.  For example:

[image]

I would like to have a solution in CSS or CSS3.  If not possible, JS is acceptable.

Comment: @harsha i havent cause nothing came to mind.. thats why i came here..

Comment: You could calculate the widths of the divs,sum them up,compare it with the width of the container,set the left positions of the divs based on the difference in widths.

Comment: @harsha if its an easy deal it could be an option , though im looking for css solution

Comment: there is no  pure solution which I could find without having non-fixed width children divs

Comment: Could you just build a quick little thing in jsfiddle to show what you mean by your boxes. Also, you may be interested in http://cssgrid.net/

Comment: What browsers do you need to support (in particular, which versions of IE)?

Comment: An interesting option would be using the flexbox display mode and `flex-pack: justify` (or `box-pack: justify` with the older standard). See http://www.the-haystack.com/2012/01/04/learn-you-a-flexbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #container {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 0; /* Fixed space caused by line breaks */
        }
        #container .inner {
            display: inline-block;
            background: red;
            width: 25%;
            border: 10px rgba(255,255,255,1) solid;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div class="inner">Lorem</div>
    <div class="inner">Ipsum</div>
    <div class="inner">Dolor</div>
    <div class="inner">Sit</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is considered slightly cheating. I'm using the white borders as margins between the elements. It would only work well if you had a solid color background on the parent.

#### Points to note:

- `box-sizing: border-box` on all element, ensures that `width: 25%` includes padding and borders inside.
- Using a white border to simulate the effect of a margin.
- Using `font-size: 0` on the parent, and `font-size: 16px` on the children, eliminates the white space caused by line-breaks between inline-block elements.

Answer (score 3):

**Possible CSS solution**

If the boxes are set to `display:inline-block`, you can apply `text-align:justify` just like you would with text. Be aware, however, that`text-align:justify` doesn't have any effect on the last line of text. So if there's only a single line that needs to be justified, nothing will happen.

One workaround for this, if you can modify the HTML, is to add a trailing element with 100% width, to ensure that the content you want to justify isn't the last line. If you're not able to modify the source HTML, a trailing element can be appended using JavaScript.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/ne7xR/4/) demonstrating this. Tested in IE6/7/8/9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari. (Note: had to add a `&nbsp;` between the boxes to get it to work in IE6/7).

Comment: +1. Perhaps you could use `:after` instead of the `force-justify` element?

Comment: @powerbuoy: Updated the demo using `:after`. It worked fine, but it wouldn't be an option for IE6/7 (depending on the browser support needed).